# Efficient query for the first result in groups (postgresql 9)

Tags: sql, grouping, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.1

I have a table with 200000 rows and columns: name and date. The dates and names may have repeated values. I would like get the first 300 unique names for the dates sorted in an ascending order and have this run fast as my table may have a million rows.

I am using postgresql 9.

Comment: How a table with 200,000 rows have a million rows?

Comment: Do you want 300 names for each "date"? Or a total of 300 rows?

Comment: There's no magic SQL trick that will let you run a query quickly over many rows. The only way is to limit the number of rows you have to look at by in the first place by using an index. (I'm not sure databases come with an index that would let you quickly get unique results.)

Comment: Also, this would be easier to answer if you gave us some example input (preferrably in the form of a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements) and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT name, date
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) name, date
    FROM table
    ORDER BY name, date
  ) AS id_date
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 300;
```

The last query of @jachguate will miss names having two dates on the same date, however this one doesn't.

The query takes about 100 ms in a non-optimized postgresql 9.1 with about 100.000 entries, thus it may not scale to millions of entries.

An upgrade to postgresql 9.2 may help, as according to the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-2.html) there are many performance improvements

Answer (score 0):

use a CTE:

```
with unique_date_name as (
       select date, name, count(*) rcount
         from table
        group by date, name
       having count(*) = 1
     )
select name, date
  from unique_date_name
 order by date limit 300;
```

**Edit**
From the comments, this result in poor performance, so try this other:

```
       select date, name, count(*) rcount
         from table
        group by date, name
       having count(*) = 1
        order by date limit 300;
```

or, transforming the original query into a nested subquery in FROM instead of a CTE:

```
select name, date
from (
       select date, name, count(*) rcount
         from table
        group by date, name
       having count(*) = 1
     ) unique_date_name
 order by date limit 300;
```

unfortunately I don't have a postgreSQL at hand to check if it works, but the optimizer will make a better work.

A Index for (date, name) is a must for optimal performance.

Comment: That'll do a seqscan and sort of the entire table before filtering, so performance is going to be horrible. It's possible you might get a closer-to-ok result by moving the CTE expression into a `FROM (SELECT ...)` query so that PostgreSQL doesn't fence it off for optimisation, but I doubt it.

Comment: I'm not sure about PostgreSQL, but with a date, name index the full scan is not needed and the optimizer must catch it.

Comment: Unfortunately, PostgreSQL treats CTEs as optimisation fences. It won't push the date filter into the CTE expression. Your query is almost equivalent (in that there may not be I/O) in PostgreSQL to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE unique_date_name AS SELECT ....;` followed by `SELECT name, date FROM unique_date_name`. There's a lot of argumennt about this at the moment on the mailing lists, as I and others strongly disagree with the current behaviour. See this thread: http://archives.postgresql.org/message-id/187F6C10D2931A4386EE8E58E13857F612917154@BLUPRD0811MB413.namprd08.prod.outlook.com

Comment: I'd argue that PostgreSQL is wrong, actually, but yes, your answer will perform very poorly for PostgreSQL. It might work better if you rephrase it as `SELECT name, date FROM (SELECT ...) unique_date_name ORDER BY date LIMIT 300;` . Pg will then push conditions down into the subquery. Annoying quirk.

Comment: Looks reasonable; I haven't mocked up any data to test with and the original question is under-specified so it's hard to say for sure.

Comment: Yes, what I'm in doubt is if the limit is applied before or after the having clause. Let's the OP try that and come tell us how's the performance and row count going.

Comment: @GeorgeVlachos Try the above, and if you have performance issues, post `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output to http://explain.depesz.com/